# Использование x86 COM в x64 приложении

Tags: c#, .net, dll, com

Ситуация следующая:

- Есть x86 com api стороннего разработчика, доступа к исходному коду
  которого нет;
- Есть x64 приложение, из которого необходимо использовать это COM.

  При использовании объектов из COM получаем очевидную ошибку.

  > "Не удалось получить фабрику класса COM для компонента с CLSID
  >   {AB8A48D1-C100-47AB-BDEE-4E2CB1619C1A} из-за следующей ошибки:
  >   80040154 Класс не зарегистрирован (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80040154
  >   (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))."

Следовательно, нам необходимо зарегистрировать типы при помощи RegAsm.exe и проксировать их вызовы через COM Surrogate (путём создания записей в реестре), либо создать COM+ приложение в "Службы компонентов", добавив туда необходимые компоненты. Подробнее об этих подходах можно почитать по этим ссылкам:

[64-Bit-Insider](https://ru.scribd.com/document/56629579/64-Bit-Insider-Volume-1-Issue-7)

[Запуск x32 COM-объектов из x64 приложения](https://kb.mista.ru/article.php?id=870)

После данных процедур (для меня сработали оба способа) типы успешно создаются, однако при вызове одного из методов COM, который должен отрисовать UI, COM+ приложение падает с сообщением "Прекращена работа программы Surrogate COM".. При этом возвращая исключение, которое ничего мне не говорит:

> Сбой при удаленном вызове процедуры. (Исключение из HRESULT:
>   0x800706BE)

Из под x86 приложения данный метод из COM нормально вызывается и UI отрисовывается. В чём может быть проблема? И знает ли кто-нибудь ещё способы вызова x86 com из x64? Возможно, тут стоит как-то использовать shared memory? Буду благодарен даже за полезные ссылки

Comment: Проблему решил абсолютно дурацким способом, переключив оболчку windows на классическую. Surrogate COM больше не падает. Кто-то может это прокомментировать? Почему именно при вызове из-под х64 это необходимо?

Comment: Поторопился.. Surrogate COM по-прежнему падает, но уже на этапе редактирования этого самого UI (например, при вводе текста в TextBox)